# MySQL Database Migration from one desktop to another desktop

Tags: mysql

I'm migrating MySQL database from desktop A to desktop B (another). Several desktops connected to desktop a through ini file with IP Address of desktop A. After migrating to desktop B, how do I carry the users and passwords as is to desktop B? When I try to open the database name (created database name on localhost, then ran the .sql file created from the export wizard of mysql workbench). I copied connections.xml from desktop A to desktop B from SQL files. However, the password is not working. Any clue how to recover? The previous developer did all the work on desktop A, and I'm trained in SQL Server, and I'm learning (coding I'm comfortable, but migration I'm struggling). Any help can I get from this forum, I would really appreciate it. I'm planning to attempt migrating again tomorrow morning 10 AM EST (Sunday). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the dev used Mysql authorization when developing the program.  You can confirm this by firing up Mysql Workbench and checking the users on Desktop A.  If you have users listed that are on Desktop A but not Desktop B then follow the below instructions.

First make sure your Mysql server versions are roughly the same on both machines.  Then in desktop A you need to backup the database named mysql which has all of the users and permissions.  Restore the .sql backup of the database named mysql to Desktop B and then reboot Desktop B.  You should then be able to login.

Comment: Thank you, I will try tomorrow. I installed MySQL (server version) and Workbench on Desktop B after going through several online MySQL links. I assume you mentioned to take the backup for the database checkbox and any checkbox that has users information to be on the SQL script. I can try. If there are any questions, I can respond tomorrow to seek an additional help. Thanks a buch.